# Entity Framework Designer Errors

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I have created a project is Visual Studio 2012 and have set up Entity framework through "Database First" approach.  However after mapping to the database and generating my Designer.cs file which is supposed to be automatically generated by the framework, I end up with heaps of errors which I can't get where they come from.  I have attached the error as a txt file for your review and professional comment.

Please take note that I'm new to the .net framework, specially the EF area.  So I'd appreciate if you give me concrete answer so that it would help along the rest of my learning curve.

> Error  1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext.DbContext(string, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbCompiledModel)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\user\Documents\TRS\TRSModel\TRSEntityModel.Designer.cs 45  32  TRSDataModel
>
> Error  2   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbCompiledModel' C:\Users\user\Documents\TRS\TRSModel\TRSEntityModel.Designer.cs 45  57  TRSDataModel
>
> Error  3   'TRSModel.TRSEntities' does not contain a definition for 'ContextOptions' and no extension method 'ContextOptions' accepting a first argument of type 'TRSModel.TRSEntities' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\user\Documents\TRS\TRSModel\TRSEntityModel.Designer.cs 47  18  TRSDataModel
>
> Error  4   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext.DbContext(string, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbCompiledModel)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\user\Documents\TRS\TRSModel\TRSEntityModel.Designer.cs 54  55  TRSDataModel
>
> Error  5   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbCompiledModel' C:\Users\user\Documents\TRS\TRSModel\TRSEntityModel.Designer.cs 54  78  TRSDataModel
>
> Error  6   'TRSModel.TRSEntities' does not contain a definition for 'ContextOptions' and no extension method 'ContextOptions' accepting a first argument of type 'TRSModel.TRSEntities' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\user\Documents\TRS\TRSModel\TRSEntityModel.Designer.cs 56  18  TRSDataModel
>
> Error  7   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext.DbContext(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, bool)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\user\Documents\TRS\TRSModel\TRSEntityModel.Designer.cs 63  59  TRSDataModel
>
> Error  8   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'bool'  C:\Users\user\Documents\TRS\TRSModel\TRSEntityModel.Designer.cs 63  76  TRSDataModel
>           Error   9   'TRSModel.TRSEntities' does not contain a definition for 'ContextOptions' and no extension method 'ContextOptions' accepting a first argument of type 'TRSModel.TRSEntities' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\user\Documents\TRS\TRSModel\TRSEntityModel.Designer.cs 65  18  TRSDataModel

```
// Lines 10-17
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.EntityClient;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Serialization;


// Lines 45-47
public TRSEntities() : base("name=TRSEntities", "TRSEntities")
{
    this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    OnContextCreated();
}

// Lines 54-56
public TRSEntities(string connectionString) : base(connectionString, "TRSEntities")
{
    this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    OnContextCreated();
}

// Lines 63-65
public TRSEntities(EntityConnection connection) : base(connection, "TRSEntities")
{
    this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    OnContextCreated();
}



// Error return by adding the public class TRSEntities to where Rene suggested 
Error   1   Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'TRSModel.TRSEntities'; another partial declaration of this type exists C:\Users\user\Documents\TRS\TRSModel\TRSEntityModel.Designer.cs 33  18  TRSDataModel
Error   2   'TRSEntities': member names cannot be the usere as their enclosing type C:\Users\user\Documents\TRS\TRSModel\TRSEntityModel.Designer.cs 40  30  TRSDataModel
```

Comment: please add the code from around line 45-47 54-56 63-65  from the TSREnitityModel.Designer.cs

Comment: The requested code piece is posted on the question area.  Please have ea look.

Comment: add the line `public class TRSEntities` upto the first { as well please

Comment: You say _which is supposed to be automatically generated by the framework_. Was it, or not?

Comment: Yes, this is an auto-generated piece of code which is generated when you change the "Code Generation Strategy" setting from "No" to "Default".  This would auto-generate your Context Object.  It indicates that changing this file could potentially render unwanted result.

Comment: I personally suspect that there is a problem referencing the ObjectContext base class since it's methods are not visible throughout the "TRSEntities" extended class.  I just can't figure out why this would be the case and where these settings should be applied for this to work.  I have also applied "rene's" change and added the public class TRSEntities to the opening {, however, I ran into two other errors which kind of make sense.  I have posted them to the question area.

Comment: When you changed the Code Gen strategy from None to Default did you remove T4 templates from your project? If not, then you might have 2 sets of entities generated for your model - POCO/DbContext and EntityObject/ObjectContext - which causes conflicts. If you want to use EntityObject/ObjectContext remove .tt files associated with edmx and set code generation strategy to default. Using POCO/DbContext is preferred. If you want to use those change code generation strategy to None and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was as I initially suspected.  The extended TRSEntities class was declared in the wrong namespace and therefore could not identify the base ObjectContext class leading to TRSEntities class not being able to access the methods of this base class.  This happened due to a change of EF name from "TRSModel" to "TRSEntityModel" which apparently did not register inside the ER engine, hence, auto-generating this context file based on the previous namespace.

One thing that I'm still not sure is how to make this change of name sink into the EF so that it would not continue assuming the old name.

Answer (score 1):

Use NuGet to EF6 instaler but must also install [tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40762) for VS2012 or VS2013 EF6

Comment: I didn't have the EF 6.x DbContext Generator object available until I installed the tools for VS2012. Get them from: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762